# spring batch | unique constraint violation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm using chunk oriented job, and using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. My reader is synchronised using `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`. And I'm getting `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '<someValue>' for key 'Ukey_someKey`. Their is a unique constraint on this column for which I'm getting the exception. There is custome logic to generate values for this unique column. Source doesn't provide duplicate values, and logic to generate random string is also fool-proof. Also, there is no entry in the db against this key. We're on mysql 5.7.33. How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: Your duplicate key entry might be in the same chunk of data / transaction. That would mean, you won't see the key in the database because your transaction is never committed, instead it will be rolled back. How do you create the key?
Please show your code with the random string key generation!
If your database reports a duplicate key, there *is* a duplicate key ;-)

Comment: Do not forget that in batch you do not make the commit after every line. So I guess you are generating the same key twice, and when the batch commit you get the error.

Comment: Is the logic that generates keys synchronized? I suspect you are in a case where a single chunk has two items with the same key, hence your error. Please share your code or a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: thank you all, for your suggestions. as suggested on looking deeper found that there was issue with the source, and that was returning duplicate records to the reader.